# Octave select part of image

Tags: octave

I have a 2-D 512x512 image and I want to display the middle section i.e. `A(256-50:256+50,256-50:256+50)` but cannot get to work using `imshow`.

Comment: Does `imshow(A)` work? Also please show your code where you used `imshow`. Also what are the range of value in the image, Integers from `0`-`255` or doubles from `0`-`1`?

Comment: Got it, used `imadjust`

Comment: @Zeus then could you please add your answer, perhaps with more details, so that this question does not appear "unanswered" ?

Comment: @Zeus - Did I answer your question on this thread? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31016858/creating-2-d-pulse-in-octave/31016874#31016874

Answer (score 1):

You can use imcrop function

```
pkg load image

x = 256-50;  // starting position (x cordinate)
y = 256-50;  // starting position (y cordinate)
a = 100;
b = 100;

B = imcrop(A, [x y a b]);
imshow(B);
```

This will crop the image starting from x,y by 100 pixels